no simplify option for expression written under Defer[] enviroment
I am new to Mathematica. I have defined following functions
p[k_, j_, n_] := 
 9 2^11 2^(6 j) k^6 - 3 2^6 2^(4 j) k^4 + 5 2^2 2^(2 j) k^2 - (n + 1)
q[j_, n_] := 
 Defer[1/(24 2^(j - 1) Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[
   1 - 29/(604 + 648 n + 9 Sqrt[4805 + 9664 n + 5184 n^2])^(
    1/3) + (604 + 648 n + 9 Sqrt[4805 + 9664 n + 5184 n^2])^(1/3)] ]

In fact, q is a root of the polynomial p and I have checked it on other software. But the problem is that
when I am evaluating p at q, I don't get zero. Furthermore, the simplify button disappeared from my screen in .nb file.
Here is my code:
p[q[j, n], j, n]

And I am getting the following answer:
-1 - n + 5 2^(
  2 + 2 j) (Sqrt[
   1 - 29/(604 + 648 n + 9 Sqrt[4805 + 9664 n + 5184 n^2])^(
    1/3) + (604 + 648 n + 9 Sqrt[4805 + 9664 n + 5184 n^2])^(1/3)]/(
   24 2^(j - 1) Sqrt[2]))^2 - 
 3 2^(6 + 4 j) (Sqrt[
   1 - 29/(604 + 648 n + 9 Sqrt[4805 + 9664 n + 5184 n^2])^(
    1/3) + (604 + 648 n + 9 Sqrt[4805 + 9664 n + 5184 n^2])^(1/3)]/(
   24 2^(j - 1) Sqrt[2]))^4 + 
 9 2^(11 + 6 j) (Sqrt[
   1 - 29/(604 + 648 n + 9 Sqrt[4805 + 9664 n + 5184 n^2])^(
    1/3) + (604 + 648 n + 9 Sqrt[4805 + 9664 n + 5184 n^2])^(1/3)]/(
   24 2^(j - 1) Sqrt[2]))^6

I know the above quantity should be equal to zero, but Mathematica is not simplifying it to make it zero.
I used Defer[] in my expression, as I don't like the way Mathematica reorders my expression. Can somebody tell me how to resolve this issue?
I have tried
Simplify[p[q[j, n], j, n]]

and
Simplify[%]

But nothing is working.

If I remove the Defer then, at least in version 14 MMA, Simplify[p[q[j,n],j,n]] promptly returns zero. Perhaps consider doing two things in parallel. One of them involves fonts and typesetting and having your expression in exactly the order and form and style that you want. And the other gets you a correct answer in a reasonable amount of time.

See also mathematica.stackexchange.com.
